# using a range for loop without using the auto keyword c++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, range, iteration

For this assignment i am supposed to use a range for to print out the elements in ia without using the auto keyword. Basically the assignment is trying to help us understand multidimentional arrays. I have an idea of what is going on in the code but i keep running into some errors. There is something wrong with the syntax and i cant figure it out.

```
int ia[3][4] = {{0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11}};

cout << endl;
for(int &a : ia)
    for(int b : a)
        cout << b << endl;
```

I keep getting these errors:

..\src\Sec_3_5_3.cpp:127:15: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
  for(int &a : ia)

..\src\Sec_3_5_3.cpp:127:15: error: cannot bind rvalue '(int)((int*)__for_begin)' to 'int&'

..\src\Sec_3_5_3.cpp:128:15: error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope

..\src\Sec_3_5_3.cpp:128:15: error: 'end' was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `ia[i]` is not an `int`, but an array of 4 `int`s.
And to be able to keep the size, you have to use a reference:

```
for(int (&a)[4] : ia)
    for(int b : a)
```